# Why is this sentence using "cognizance" instead of "awareness"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I understand the meaning of *cognizance* is "knowledge, awareness or notice." However, for a given situation why should I use *cognizance* instead of *knowledge* or *awareness* or *notice*?

Take the below example from "Emotional Intelligence" by Daniel Goleman.

> By objective of this book is how to bring intelligence to emotion. This understanding itself can help to some degree; bringing cognizance to the realm of feeling has an effect something like the impact of an observer at the quantum level physics.

Why did the author use *cognizance* instead of *awareness*?
Does *cognizance* carry an extra value or weight than *awareness*?
What is special about *cognizance*?

Answer (score 7):

To some extent, it is a matter of style.  The author likes that word better.

There are, however differences between those words.

- *Awareness* has inflections that relate to perception*: I'm aware of something if I can see, hear, smell, touch or taste it. You can be *aware* of something and not *know* very much about it.
- *Knowledge* is an intellectual attribute and includes facts and information that have been acquired*. You can *know* facts about a subject, yet still not have a real *cognizance* of it.
- *Cognizance* relates to formal knowledge and comes from the Latin root, to learn<sup>*</sup>.

So, in terms of its 'perception' meaning, *awareness* is not nearly distinct enough from *feeling* and the distinction is what the author is trying to highight.  The word awareness would not convey the correct meaning in this instance.

The knowledge vs cognizance issue isn't quite as obvious, but essentially, you can know about feelings (or 'the realm of feeling') without understanding it, and simple knowledge isn't quite what the author is trying to convey.  He is talking about knowledge with understanding and so has opted for cognizance which carries that meaning better.

Other words which would also have worked (ie carried the full meaning of cognizance) include: understanding, comprehension and possibly perspicacity (though the last relates more to the ability of the person to understand than to the subject being understood).

A suggestion: Don't just look at Google results for 'define wordOfInterest' when you are trying to understand subtleties between word choices. Check multiple online (and/or hardcopy) dictionaries in both US and UK English to give yourself the best chance of understanding (or becoming cognizant).

<sup>*</sup> Definitions from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com).

Answer (score 3):

For all practical purposes, they have the same meaning. "Awareness" is used much more commonly than "cognizance". Perhaps the author felt that it sounded more erudite.